# Конвертация цифр прописью

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Задание:

Введенный номер телефона будет состоять только из цифр. Выведите название каждой цифры в новой строке.
Например: ввод - 4901825;
вывод -
четыре
девять
нуль
один
восемь
два
пять.

Запускаю, пишет, что имя m не определено. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

```
import re
replace = {
    "0": "zero", 
    "1": "one", 
    "2": "two", 
    "3": "three", 
    "4": "four", 
    "5": "five", 
    "6": "six", 
    "7": "seven", 
    "8": "eight", 
    "9": "nine"}
def re_numbers(m):
    return replace[m.group(0)]
re.sub(r"\d", re_numbers, input())
print(re_numbers(m))
```

Comment: `print(re.sub(r"\d", re_numbers, input()))` ?

Comment: @MaxU ,  спасибо, помогло!!!)))))

Comment: @MaxU , а как сделать, чтоб он распечатывал ни в строчку, а в столбик - каждый раз с новой строчки?!

Comment: добавить перевод строки к возвращаемому значению в функции `re_numbers()`. PS а вообще я не понимаю зачем здесь регулярки??

Comment: @MaxU , я знаю, что лучше бы через цикл for такое делать. Но я хочу через регулярки. Бабский каприз.