# nuw2words - в строке заменить числа на буквы

Tags: python, строки

Как из строки `"1привет2"` получить строку `"один привет два"` ?

Comment: Что получится из `42друга`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326275/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8E

Answer (score 1):

```
s="1привет2"
c={'1':'один','2':'два','3':'три','4':'четыре','5':'пять','6':'шесть','7':'семь','8':'восемь','9':'девять','0':'ноль'}
res=''
for ch in s:
    if ch in '1234567890':
        res+=' '+c[ch]+' '
    else:
        res+=ch
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение @Oopss хорошее, но требует небольшой доработки.
Его программа даст результат " один привет два ", а требуется "один привет два". Вот доработанная версия:

```py
s="1привет2"
c={'1':'один','2':'два','3':'три','4':'четыре','5':'пять','6':'шесть','7':'семь','8':'восемь','9':'девять','0':'ноль'}
res=''
len_s = len(s)
for i, ch in enumerate(s):
    if ch in '1234567890':
        if i == 0:
            res += c[ch] + ' '
            continue
        if i == len_s - 1:
            res += ' ' + c[ch]
            continue
        res+=' '+c[ch]+' '
    else:
        res+=ch
print(res)
```